# How do I keep nagging the user to accept iPhone Safari's geo location?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I have a web page that requests HTML5 geo location from user.

What if on the iPhone the user denies it?

I want to prompt him again. How do I prompt him? (I want to keep prompting him until he accepts. He cannot visit any page until he accepts)

Comment: I guess it's not possible to do this with javascript. The only way I can think of, is to get the accuracy of your current position and ask the user to enable the geo location manually if the accuracy is too bad. Or disable your page for the error code `PERMISSION_DENIED`.

Comment: But user has tendency to stop using an app that nags.

Answer (score 0):

Your app has to account for users not wanting to be tracked.

Create a page where the user doesn't want to use geolocation, and say something along the lines like this application requires geolocation, go away...